# Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : all variables in design formula must be columns in colData

Tags: r

I need help fixing error

Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : all variables in design formula must be columns in colData

sample_info_tab datacount_tab data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qag1o.png)

count_tab data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo0zI.png)

The code I used was

deseq_counts <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(count_tab, colData = sample_info_tab, design = ~type)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the `design` that you choose must be the name of a column from your metadata (`sample_info_tab datacount_tab`). In this case, since you put in '`type`', you should make sure that you have a column that is named '`type`' in your `sample_info_tab datacount_tab` file. Try changing the design to the name of a column in your file that separates the data into the two '`types`' you wanna compare, or create a new column that will do so. Also, if I'm correct, the function is also case sensitive, so be sure to check it really matches. Good luck!